# Construct polygons from axis-aligned intervals

Tags: computational-geometry, intervals, polygons

### Scenario

Consider **one or more curved shapes** in 2D space, clipped to a rectangular viewport. For example:

[image: original]

Unfortunately, data that would describe these shapes precisely, is not available.

### Input data

All that is available are the **intersections** of the shapes with a few horizonal and vertical lines, sampled at coarse intervals:

[image: horizonal intervals]
[image: vertical intervals]

In the example at hand, the available data could be expressed like this:

```
y    x-ranges
-------------------------
 0   0.0 - 2.2
 1   0.0 - 4.3
 2   0.0 - 4.2
 3   0.0 - 3.7, 6.8 - 8.5
 4   0.0 - 3.6, 6.6 - 8.6
 5   0.0 - 3.8, 6.7 - 8.4
 6   0.0 - 4.7
 7   0.0 - 1.1, 3.1 - 5.3
 8   0.0 - 0.2, 3.5 - 5.2
 9   
10   


x    y-ranges
-------------------------
 0   0.0 - 8.4
 1   0.0 - 7.1
 2   0.0 - 6.5
 3   0.3 - 6.8
 4   0.5 - 2.4, 5.3 - 8.8
 5   6.2 - 8.5
 6   
 7   2.7 - 5.4
 8   2.5 - 5.5
 9   
10
```

It's not much, but when both sets of intervals are combined, it already allows a human viewer to "see" the original shapes quite well:

[image: all intervals]

### The Problem

But how would a **computer algorithm** go about approximating the outlines of the original shapes based on data like this?

Ignoring interpolation/smoothing for now, the problem becomes **grouping and ordering** the interval end-points in the correct manner to get the ordered vertices of one or more **polygons** corresponding to the original shapes:

[image: polygons]

In the example at hand, the output data of the algorithm could be expressed like this:

```
Polygon 1:
(0, 0) - (0, 8.4) - (0.2, 8) - (1, 7.1) - (1.1, 7) - (2, 6.5) - (3, 6.8) - (3.1, 7) - (3.5, 8) - (4, 8.8) - (5, 8.5) - (5.2, 8) - (5.3, 7) - (5, 6.2) - (4.7, 6) - (4, 5.3) - (3.8, 5) - (3.6, 4) - (3.7, 3) - (4, 2.4) - (4.2, 2) - (4.3, 1) - (4, 0.5) - (2.2, 0) - (0, 0)

Polygon 2:
(7, 2.7) - (6.8, 3) - (6.6, 4) - (6.7, 5) - (7, 5.4) - (8, 5.5) - (8.4, 5) - (8.6, 4) - (8.5, 3) - (8, 2.5) - (7, 2.7)
```

### Help needed

I'm having trouble coming up with an algorithm to do this. I'd greatly appreaciate:

- Clarity on what kind of problem this is, what kind of algorithm is needed, etc.
  *(Part of what makes this difficult for me is that I don't know what search terms to use to research this.)*
- Pointers to edge cases etc. that I need to consider, that I may not yet have.
- Pointers to appropriate literature.
- Suggestions/discussions of the algorithm itself, obviously.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you want to compute the boundary of your interval-defined areas. In particular, you want to identify the vertices of the boundary and how to connect them. Is this correct?

Comment: @Discretelizard: Yeah. Note that the input already contains all the polygon vertices -- the problem is deciding which vertices belong to the same polygon, and in which order they need to be connected within each polygon.

Comment: One simple heuristic is: for each point, find its two nearest neighbors, and connect it to those two neighbors.  This works if the shapes aren't too close together.  Does it suffice for your needs?  (If you have a bound on how sharp the curvature of the perimeter is, you could also test that the angle between these three points is not too sharp.) You can improve this a bit, e.g., if a point $P$ is an endpoint of a vertical line, look for the closest neighbor to the right of $P$, and the closest neighbor to the left of $P$, and connect $P$ to those two neighbors.

Comment: Do you always have both horizontal and vertical intervals for each disconnected shape? In that case, the problem of separating the shapes reduces to finding connected components in the intersection graph of the intervals.

Comment: @D.W. I'm trying out "nearest neighbors that can be reached without crossing a sampling line or an existing polygon line". Might need to backtrack to exclude paths that don't form closed polygons. Let's see how my prototype implementation will fare.

Comment: @Discretelizard: Unfortunately, no - in fact, as an extreme case, there might *only* be vertical intervals.

Comment: @smls If an arbitrary amount of intervals could be 'missing', separating the shapes requires a form of clustering (on the whole intervals, of course). You _could_ try to construct the boundaries without explicitely checking for separate shapes, but this could easily lead to inconsistencies. If you make no other assumptions on your shapes, 'nearest non-crossing neighbour' does look like a reasonable approach once we determined the shapes each point belongs to.